Setting up Managed Identity authentication for Azure Storage Account
I have Azure Storage account Gen2 (Azure Datalake) on which I want to set MSI(Managed Identity) authentication.
Goal is to access ADLS from the application which is using Azure SDK for CPP and which should use Azure::Identity::ManagedIdentityCredential.
My concerns is where I am doing wrong, Azure or Code?
I tried to use Azure::Identity::ManagedIdentityCredential using only client id for now.
On the Azure side I did exactly this.

Created ADLS Gen2 account
Created managed Identity
Went back to ADLS Gen2 account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment -> Role Storage Account Contributor -> Members Managed identity -> +Select members -> selected managed identity created in step 2
Went back to the application, and for Client ID I have used the Client ID from Managed Identity

As result, request for GetToken timeout 3 times and it stops.

Where are you trying to use Managed Identity auth from? It only works inside Azure services where the endpoint for it is available.

You should not use managed identity like this. should be the pattern: A resource (such as vm)combine with managed identity, and the resource (vm) access additional azure resources.

@juunas I am trying to use it from my application which is using azure sdk for cpp (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-cpp)
I have endpoint to the blobstorage available, I can use any other authentication from SDK except for ManagedIdentityCredential

@JohnDoe Whether you needs to authenticate with ManagedIdentityCredential or Any other also fine for you like Defaultazurecredential?

If outside azure environment, you can also use the Clientsecretcredential to authenticate the azure storage account.

Managed Identity only works when your application runs on an Azure service that supports it.
For example, on an Azure Virtual Machine, Managed Identity tokens are acquired from the Instance Metadata Service (IMDS) endpoint only accessible from inside the VM.
Think about it. If you could get access to a Storage account by just knowing a GUID (the client ID), that would not be very secure, would it? ;)
You'll need to use a credential that uses your user account, e.g. Azure CLI credential or Default Azure credential.
Or register an application in Entra ID with a client secret/certificate and use the relevant credential for that.

Aha, that does makes sense. Whole environment is bit confusing to understand. I am logging via other auth types without problems, I just wanted to create an environment to use MSI as well.
If I understood you well I could do it but on different level.

Create Azure VM and deploy my app on it
From that VM access Azure Blob Storage which allowed VM from 1. access using Managed Identity

Am I right?

Yup, that's correct. You can either enable a system-assigned managed identity on the VM or create a user-assigned managed identity and assign it to the VM. System-assigned is deleted if the VM is deleted and can only be used by that VM. User-assigned is its individual resource and can be assigned to several resources. Note that if you use system-assigned, you don't specify the client ID. With user-assigned, you should specify the client ID.

Ok, thanks. It's sound really complicated. Is there maybe some good tutorial for doing such thing? Because there are bunch of those on the internet and I am not sure which ones are bad and which are good.

This one on MS docs looks ok: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-managed-identities-vm-access?pivots=identity-windows-mi-vm-access-storage Some of the UI has been updated in Azure but the concepts are the same. Code sample is in C#, but you would just use the ManagedIdentityCredential to get the access token or use the credential with a Storage SDK.

This is what I have tried.

Create VM -> enable system identity -> Create ADLS -> ADLS IAM, add VM -> BadRequest
Create VM -> enable user identity -> Add Managed Identity -> in ADLS in IAM add same Managed Identity -> use every possible ID -> Bad Request...

Do you have idea what I've been doing wrong?

This is code used ||||||||
auto credentials= std::make_sharedAzure::Identity::ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId, options);

Is there any more information in the error? Azure often returns error details in the response body.

https://pastebin.com/d9L6HYUt
Its Bad Request. I have tried to put any value for ClientId it's still bad request.
Is it possible due to fact that I have been using tag 12.10.0 BlobStorage and not the latest azure sdk for cpp where it has option to specify what are you using Object or Client Id?

Hmm, you could try that new version, though I'd somehow expect the older one to work too.

I will try. But from the setup, everything seems ok?

It does sound correct.

Ok, I'll replace SDK and provide feedback.

I've replaced SDK with azure sdk for cpp azure-identity_1.10.0 and now it works. But still I'm not sure it's correct, because even without adding any role to the storage account I can access it from the VM. Is it because of public access in the network? Can I somehow provide access only to the application I specifically add to the role?

What have you set for "Public access" on the container in Storage? It should be set to None, so that authorization is required.

Container -> Anonymous access level = Private
Storage account -> Networking = Enabled from all networks
I'm not sure where is the option you mentioned above, could you please help me?

Ah, I meant the Anonymous access level. It should not be possible for it to access the Storage account without some kind of role assignment then..

I put Allow Blob anonymous access to Disabled and removed role on storage account for the VM, but when I try to access to the storage account it works.
Is it because in Networking it is set
Public network access
Enabled from all networks?
